# Which images were used primarily for navigation algorithms on the Spirit rover?

Tags: mars, rovers, spirit, opportunity

I've noticed a lot of variations on the MER image data: we have RDR, EDR, and a whole lot of images that haven't been corrected yet (which appear mostly black in colour). On top of this, in the PDS databases, we have a collection of panoramic images and cropped images. I've read through a few papers on computer vision on the MER, but it hasn't specified which data they use.

[Analyst's Notebook](http://an.rsl.wustl.edu/mer/)

[PDS Geosciences Node](http://geo.pds.nasa.gov/missions/mer/geo_mer_datasets.htm)

I'm designing an algorithm for terrain estimation using MER data, and in order to get as realistic results as possible, I want to use the data that the rover actually uses to navigate. Which data collections should I be looking at?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is the images from the "Navigation Camera". As explained [here](http://mars.nasa.gov/mer/home/posters/OpportunityPosterBack.pdf), the mast-mounted stereo imagers collectively referred to as the "Navigation Camera" were used for navigation.

You can browse the collection of images from the Navigation Camera here:

http://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/all/spirit.html

You didn't mention Opportunity, but it is available as well:

http://mars.nasa.gov/mer/gallery/all/opportunity.html

Just select one of the [sols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars#Sols) available under the "Navigation Camera" heading and click the "View Selected Sol" button. The images for that sol will appear in the new page.

The body-mounted Hazard Avoidance cameras assisted in navigation as well, and you should also see the headings for them listed at the above links as "Hazcam".